# Use of incomplete types with std::variant

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variant

Suppose I have next code, that is used for simply storing reference/pointer to objects of types `A`, `B` or `C`. I actually don't need complete types.

Now i have the following solution, where I need a lot of #include bloat.

Header:

```cpp
using MyVariant = std::variant<class A, class B, class C, ...>;

class Holder {
public:
  Holder(MyVariant &&TheValue);

  const MyVariant &GetValue();
  
private:
  std::unique_ptr<MyVariant> Value;
};
```

Source file:

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"

Holder::Holder(MyVariant &&TheValue)
  : Value(std::make_unique<MyVariant>(std::move(TheValue)) {}

const MyVariant &Holder::GetValue { return Value; }
```

How I can implement the same semantics without all instantiated types as std::variant template parameters / dynamic memory allocation / dynamic polymorphism?

Comment: If you just want to hold pointers, then why not `std::variant<A*, B*, C*>`? (or `std::unique_ptr` equivalent).

Comment: I want to avoid a lot of `new` calls, so i can't allocate object on stack and pass pointer to it. Instead of this, i want normally hold a value itself.

Comment: In your current solution, why `std::unique_ptr<MyVariant> Value;` instead of `MyVariant Value;`? That'll put the variant on the stack even for an automatic `Holder` instance.

Comment: Because std::variant needs all instantiated types for this. I want to keep header files minimal.

Comment: @385i If you want `std::variant` to actually hold the types without indirection, then they logically must be complete, because `std::variant` needs to know how much memory to reserve for them.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Comment: @385i `variant` won't work with incomplete type for the same reason there is no work around that satisfies all your requirements. You want the object to store the values in-place (with no external memory). For this, the object must be at least as large as the largest type it can hold. For this, it must know the size of each type it can hold. And for this, each type must be complete (you can't get the size of an incomplete type) which contradicts your requirement that the types be incomplete.

Comment: What are the design decisions behind keeping the number of included header files down  below what would be needed to create otherwise reasonable classes?

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out the specifications seem a little contradicting.
I can only think of variable template arguments, to achieve not having to specify all possible classes for the `Holder` class.

[Example](https://replit.com/@TobiasGepp/Variant#main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <variant>

// h

template<typename ...T>
class Holder {
  using variant = std::variant<T...>;
public:
  Holder(variant &&TheValue) 
  :Value(std::make_unique<variant>(std::move(TheValue)))
  {
  };
  
  template<typename TARGET>
  const TARGET &GetValue() const {
    return std::get<TARGET>(*Value);
  };
  
private:
  std::unique_ptr<variant> Value;
};

// main.cpp testing
int main() {
  auto a = Holder<int, float>(5);
  const auto v = a.GetValue<int>();
  std::cout << "holding int: " << v << std::endl;

  a = Holder<int, float>(5.5f);
  const auto v2 = a.GetValue<float>();
  std::cout << "holding float: " << v2 << std::endl;
}
```

I think at that point it looks like a rather redundant class though.